# How can I access table cells in particular column to convert format

Tags: javascript

I got from AJAX query a string like this:

> var ansverStr = "[1,\"Bedford Street\",\"Oxford Circus, Green Park or
>   Westminster\",\"15\",\"Regent Street\",1343329406000]\r\n[1,\"Bedford
>   Street\",\"Oxford Circus, Green Park or Westminster\",\"13\",\"Golders
>   Green\",1343329883000]\r\n[1,\"Bedford Street\",\"Oxford Circus, Green
>   Park or Westminster\",\"176\",\"Tottenham Ct
>   Rd\",1343329612000]\r\n[1,\"Bedford Street\",\"Oxford Circus, Green
>   Park or Westminster\",\"91\",\"Trafalgar
>   Sq\",1343329514000]\r\n[1,\"Bedford Street\",\"Oxford Circus, Green
>   Park or Westminster\",\"11\",\"Fulham
>   Broadway\",1343329434000]\r\n[1,\"Bedford Street\",\"Oxford Circus,
>   Green Park or
>   Westminster\",\"87\",\"Wandsworth\",1343330102000]\r\n[1,\"Bedford
>   Street\",\"Oxford Circus, Green Park or
>   Westminster\",\"6\",\"Willesden Gar\",1343329673000]\r\n[1,\"Bedford
>   Street\",\"Oxford Circus, Green Park or
>   Westminster\",\"91\",\"Trafalgar Sq\",1343329871000]\r\n[1,\"Bedford
>   Street\",\"Oxford Circus, Green Park or Westminster\",\"11\",\"Fulham
>   Broadway\",1343329743000]"

Then created a dynamic table for it

> var element;
>
> element = ''
>   + ansverStr.split('\r\n').map(function(line){
>       return '' + JSON.parse(line).map(function(cell){
>           return '' + cell + '';
>       }).join('') + ''; }).join('') + ''; 
>   document.getElementById("bStop").innerHTML=element;

The last field in ansverStr substrings is a time.

**The question:
How can I access to those values in dynamic table to convert them into time format**

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Rather than posting all of this messy code, your question should have been "How to convert Epoch time to a JavaScript Date object".

Answer (score 0):

Using proper Json formatting will make it very simple to retrieve results http://jsfiddle.net/wzBFC/1/

```
var myJSONObject = {"results": [
     {"street_number": 1,"street":"Bedford Street","city":"Oxford Circus, Green Park or Westminster","address2":"15","street2":"Regent  Street","timestamp":1343329406000},
     {"street_number": 1,"street":"Bedford Street","city":"Oxford Circus, Green Park or Westminster","address2":"15","street2":"Regent  Street","timestamp":1343329407000}
     ] };    

     timeStamp = new Date(myJSONObject.results[1].timestamp);    
     alert(timeStamp);
```

Comment: This wasn't a question, my problem is how to access those values.
Look at the header: 'Accessing table cells  ... '
I also rephrased the question

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, the edit should make it clear.